# React admin: Can I create two resources using one form?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have two resources: `Hardware` and `Product`.
The hardware depends on the Product.

All examples suggest using one `Create/Edit` form for one resource.
**Can I change this behavior?**

For better UX, I want to create a product seamlessly.
Users should see just one form with inputs from the two resources.

Of course, the `product` must be created before using it's identifier as a foreign key while creating `hardware`.

Do you have similar examples?

Comment: welcome to so, you question lacks research effort, stackoverflow suggests to read [how to ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), FROM REVIEW

Comment: You can check this link to create a custom Toolbar where you can change the default behavior. https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#toolbar

Comment: What is your backend running on? Maybe it is easier to just do it there.

Comment: A specific tutorial from the 4.X docs: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AdvancedTutorials.html#creating-a-record-related-to-the-current-one. This links to https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/09/16/react-admin-tutorials-form-for-related-records.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *All examples suggest using one Create/Edit form for one resource.*
> *Can I change this behavior?*

The wonderful team at Marmelab write the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Readme.html) to focus on showing the key aspects so that you appreciate the basic building blocks of `react-admin`.

But **yes, it's possible to one `Create/Edit` form with multiple resources**.
And all the magic lies in the [Toolbar](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/CreateEdit.html#toolbar), and here's what the team says:

> At the bottom of the form, the toolbar displays the submit button.
> You can override this component by setting the `toolbar` prop, to display the buttons of your choice.

And once you have buttons of your choice, you have all the freedom to handle multiple `<Resource>`s (of course, you must declare those resources within the `<Admin>` component).

Here's an example of what i've done multiple times.
And i'll use it in context of - `hardware` and `product` - your resources.

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as request from 'superagent'; // HTTP request library
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useFormState } from 'react-final-form'; // react-admin forms are based on this
import {
  Create, 
  SaveButton, 
  SimpleForm, 
  Toolbar, 
  useRedirect,
  useNotify
} from 'react-admin';

// main "create' component
export const ProductCreate = props => {
  return (
      <Create {...props}>
         // we override the "toolbar" prop by passing a custom toolbar
         <SimpleForm toolbar={<ProductCreateToolbar/>} {...props}>
           ...
         </SimpleForm>
      </Create>
  );
};


// Handling "create" mode
const ProductCreateToolbar = props => {
  return (
    <Toolbar {...props}>
      <ProductSaveButton {...props} /> 
    </Toolbar>
  )  
};

// define the "save/create" button
const ProductSaveButton = props => {
  const formState = useFormState();
  const redirectTo = useRedirect();
  const notify = useNotify();

  const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token'); // often created after "login" success

  const {
    // form fields related to "product" e.g.
    productName,
    productSize,
    productCost,
    // form fields related to "hardware" e.g.
    hardwareName,
    hardwareLocation
    ...other
  } = formState && formState.values;
  // Note: useFormState() gets fields based on the "source" prop of the inputs.

  const handleSave = () => {
    
    // based on any HTTP request library e.g. superagent
    apiCall(
      { ... },    // data to create "product"
      token,      // needed if the endpoints are protected
      'post',     // basically the HTTP POST
      'products/' // replace with actual endpoint to create a product
    ).then(res => {       
       
       // check for a response
       if (response) {          
          const { status, body } = res; 
         
          // if the "product" has been created
          if (status === 200 || status === 201) {

             // pick the "product id" 
             // or specific foreign-key to create a "hardware"
             let productId = body['id'];
             
             apiCall(
                { product_id: productId, ...other } // data to create "hardware"
                token,
                'post',
                'hardwares/' // replace with actual endpoint to create a hardware
             ).then(res => {

                 if (res) {
                    const { status } = res;

                    if (status === 200 || status === 201) {
                       
                       // display toast message to user
                       notify(`Product and hardware have been created successfully`, "info");
                       // redirect to products list
                       redirectTo('list', basePath);

                    } else {
                       // any action if create fails
                    };
                   
                 };

             }).catch(
                error => console.error('Error while saving:', error)
             );             

          };

       };
    }).catch(
       error => console.error('Error while saving:', error)
    );
  }

  return (
    <SaveButton
      {...props}
      label="Save"
      submitOnEnter={false}
      saving={loading}
      onSave={handleSave} // handles the create
    />
  );
};

// for making the HTTP requests (used within the toolbar buttons)
const apiCall = (data, header, type, url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request[type](`http://localhost:8000/api/${url}`)
      .send(data)
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + header)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (res) {
          return resolve(res.body);
        }
        return reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

Please note that `react-admin` provides [specialized hooks](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/Actions.html#specialized-hooks).
And you can do that above by calling the `useCreate` hook twice (for "product" and 'hardware") but you WILL NOT have as much control over the process as what I have demonstrated above.